# An initial value problem for $p_t+ap_x = f(x,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential

[image]
Consider the portion of this solution where $p(x,t)= \displaystyle  \frac{2}{a}$.

For this case, why doesn't $ p(x,0) = \displaystyle \frac{2}{a}$?  If it did, this would clearly contradict the initial value condition because $a > 0 \Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{2}{a} > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if $t=0$ then you will never hit that case, since $x$ could not simultaneously be both $\geq 1$ and $\leq -1$.

Comment: Thanks!  So then how does someone check that portion of the answer for the initial value?

Is it sufficient to show that the initial value condition is met during the intervals in which the condition exists?

Comment: I haven't thought about initial value problems in many years, but I would say that you need to graph the five regions described in the solution (in the (t,x) plane) and then look at the parts which touch t=0. On t=0 you need to make sure that the solution agrees with 2/a, and as you approach t=0 from any direction you need to make sure that the limits of the expressions for those directions are also 2/a